# ImageView in tableview cell not taking whole width from leading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `TableView` and have an `ImageView` in the cell which takes the whole width. I have set all the leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints but still, it's not working.
There is always some leading space like the `ImageView` is not stretching to leading and I have changed the content view background colour to show my issue clearly.

[image]

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Please share screenshots of `UIImageView`'s constraints

Comment: kindly see picture links are attached. I'm not allowed to attach images right now

Comment: Can you share your imageView's code?

Comment: if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countrycell", for: indexPath) as? ApplySectionCell {
            cell.imageView?.image = imagesArray[indexPath.section]
        //    cell.imageView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth , .flexibleHeight]
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true


         cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
       cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
cell.clipsToBounds = true
            return cell}

Comment: Can I email you my project and you can have a look please? I'm really stressed already wasted 9 hours on this bug

Comment: @AhsanMughal, check my answer please.

Comment: what's your answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507328/11834979

Comment: @AhsanMughal, Did you try it?

Comment: yes didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move cell to separate nib and then register that nib in viewDidLoad and in cellForRowAt call that cell
Put one view like mainView in contentView and then you can put constraints to that mainView and play it with that.
You should avoid putting cells inside tableView direct it is messy to look at it :D

Comment: Thanks mate.It really worked like a magic.Wasted a lot of time on this.
Thanks again for suggesting a different approach :)

Answer (score 0):

@Ahsan Mughal

Try this I hope it will overcome your issue.

```
contentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: I have wasted almost 8 hours on this

Comment: @Ahsan Mughal Make sure you have put corner radius for both contentView and imageView? and Make sure also seems maybe your image view having corners only on top and bottom left?

Comment: @AhsanMughal Then seems issue on your `leftAnchor` Constraint. If you set `10 pixel` on left anchor, you need to set `0`. Try this and If still not fixed could you show your tableView cell ?

Comment: Exactlyyy but I have leading constraint set to 0. This is making me mad

Comment: @AhsanMughal Then you must show your code what have you done on UITableViewCell for need to find the mistakes.

Comment: if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countrycell", for: indexPath) as? ApplySectionCell {
   cell.imageView?.image = imagesArray[indexPath.section]
   cell.imageView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth , .flexibleHeight]
   cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
   cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
 cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
      cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                      cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
                      cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
                      cell.clipsToBounds = true return cell

Comment: with this I have all constraints set to zero like top,left,right,bottom

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        let currentImage = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
        guard let imageCrop = currentImage?.getCropRatio() else { return 1.77 }
        return tableView.frame.width / imageCrop
        
    }
This code I'm using to get the crop ratio

Comment: @AhsanMughal May I know the reason for `getCropRatio()` on heightForRowAt ? Could you try with Automatic dimension for UITableViewCell height?

Comment: @AhsanMughal Could you try without this `cell.imageView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth , .flexibleHeight]` ?

Comment: If I don't use this and set my constraints to top left right bottom..

Comment: Then I get a very small image and this warning
Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a table view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead. Cell: <Qorsat.ApplySectionCell: 0x7f9f0766eb50; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 15; 374 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003ddad80>>

Comment: @AhsanMughal Then try with Static height and of course you should set top left right bottom on your constraints. Then your tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0 and tableView.rowHeight = .automaticDimension.

Comment: Can I mail you my project and you can see the bug? I'll be very grateful to you because I think I can't do this now wasted 9 hours

Comment: Again I'll be veryy grateful If you can have a look at my code please? I'm stressed.

Comment: @AhsanMughal sent ?

Comment: uploading on github and then will send you link

Comment: Can I send you just cell file and storyboard file?

Comment: Actually It's taking time to upload

Answer (score 0):

```
*Do following steps:
1) Change constraints with equalHeightsToSuperview,centerHorizontally,centerVertically,and a constant width.
2) Take outlet of the constant width constraint and while on runtime you should change the widthConstraint.constant = <WidthOfTheCell> in cell class
3)write self.layoutIfNeeded() in cell class
This is a new behavior/issue of the imageview in cell which inherits the size of Image and overrides the given constraints.*
```

Comment: but why I need to do that when I'm trying to achieve a simple thing

Comment: Yes...share me on adiash31@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Just add a background color to your `imageview`, then see if the `imageview` is aligned to `top/left/right/bottom`. if yes then please check the `imageview`'s contentMode if it is `centered` or `aspect fit`. in that case change that to `scale to fill` or `Aspect Fill`

Answer (score 0):

### Swift

```
imgYourImageView.contentMode = .center
```

Try with them and check for proper size image you can use the following options to position your image:

- `scaleAspectFit`   // contents scaled to fit with fixed
  aspect. remainder is transparent
- `redraw` // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
- `center` // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
- `scaleToFill`
- `top`
- `bottom`
- `left`
- `right`
- `topLeft`
- `topRight`
- `bottomLeft`
- `bottomRight`

Happy Coding...!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `imageview`'s `leading constraint` isn't relative to the `superview`'s margin.

Also, debug and inspect your view hierarchy to see if you spot any constraints that look suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are referencing "imageView", which is a default image container provided by tableviewcell.

Please check if you are referencing the correct ImageView, the one you created as an IBOutlet and set all the constraints with.

Comment: I have my own imageview with custom cell class

Comment: I have done this type of stuff multiple times but this time I'm literally stressed I'm not able to find the issue

Comment: buddy the ```cell.imageView?.image = imagesArray[indexPath.section]``` the optional is alarming "?", did you declare the IBOutlet as an optional type?

Comment: check the reference if it is properly created .. the thing is ```cell.imageView``` exists by default in tableviewcell .. I feel like you are referencing that instead of your own ..